# div tag line bar height issue

Tags: html, css

I'm create small two line bar  , I have some issue,  I'm change height  `height: 5rem;` that height is always change top to bottom , how to make it correctly  ? 
I want to know how to make it correctly increase - bottom to top,(I cant correctly explain that issue,I don't have any idea for this issue, please look my code you can understand it )

look example image (i need like this)

[image]

```css
.book-event-one {
    position:absolute; /*Parent MUST be relative*/
    z-index: 9;

    /*Set width/height of the div in 'parent'*/
    display: block;
    background-color: #009193;
    width: 0.5rem;margin-left: 0.2rem;
    height: 2rem;
  }
  
  
  .book-event-two {
    position:absolute; /*Parent MUST be relative*/
    z-index: 9;
    margin-left: 0.8rem;
    /*Set width/height of the div in 'parent'*/
    display: block;
    background-color: #ff9300;
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 5rem;
  }
```

```html
 



<div class="book-event-one"></div><div class="book-event-two"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify position while using absolute property.

```
.book-event-one, .book-event-two {
 bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap both bars on a main div. Add the next css to that div

```
.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

Once you have done that just add bottom: 0 to both bars.

Hope it solves your problem.

```css
.book-event-one {
  position: absolute;
  /*Parent MUST be relative*/
  z-index: 9;
  /*Set width/height of the div in 'parent'*/
  display: block;
  background-color: #009193;
  width: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  bottom: 0;
}

.book-event-two {
  position: absolute;
  /*Parent MUST be relative*/
  z-index: 9;
  margin-left: 0.8rem;
  /*Set width/height of the div in 'parent'*/
  display: block;
  background-color: #ff9300;
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="book-event-one"></div>
  <div class="book-event-two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Since the `position: absolute` for both, they will always stick to top (default behavior) unless you specified a `bottom value.`

Wrap both `div`'s with a regular `div` and give it `position: relative` then add `bottom: 0` for both children

```css
.book-event-one {
    position:absolute; /*Parent MUST be relative*/
    z-index: 9;

    /*Set width/height of the div in 'parent'*/
    display: block;
    background-color: #009193;
    width: 0.5rem;margin-left: 0.2rem;
    height: 2rem;
  }
  
  
  .book-event-two {
    position:absolute; /*Parent MUST be relative*/
    z-index: 9;
    margin-left: 0.8rem;
    /*Set width/height of the div in 'parent'*/
    display: block;
    background-color: #ff9300;
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 5rem;
  }
  .book-event-one,
  .book-event-two {
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;height: 5rem"><div class="book-event-one"></div><div class="book-event-two"></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Check the JSfiddle link ,hope you will get your required outcome.

```css
#outer-div{
  border:1px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
}
.book-event-one {
    position:absolute; /*Parent MUST be relative*/
    z-index: 9;

    /*Set width/height of the div in 'parent'*/
    display: block;
    background-color: #009193;
    width: 0.5rem;margin-left: 0.2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    bottom:0;
    /* border:1px solid green */
  }
  
  
  .book-event-two {
    position:absolute; /*Parent MUST be relative*/
    z-index: 9;
    margin-left: 0.8rem;
    /*Set width/height of the div in 'parent'*/
    display: block;
    background-color: #ff9300;
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    bottom:0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <div class="book-event-one"></div><div class="book-event-two"></div>
</div>
```

Note:-just comment border css for outer div ,I kept to just for reference

Comment: Thanks for the solution